# Is there a way of replaying a .pcap and "broadcast" it?

Tags: tcp, udp, wireshark, broadcast, pcap

I have .pcap files that I want to replay just as they are and were recorded. I have tried with Colasoft and Playcap with no success. In Wireshark the file is shown correctly with IP Adresses and Protocol (all of them are UDPs). When getting "replayed" by Colasoft's Packet Player (and shown with Packet Builder) they are not recognized with the same "structure" as Wireshark does. I understand .pcap is not the format these programs are expecting, so I could get that. (in the Docu .pcap is not mentioned)
PlayCap is showing the same. (See screenshot). Wireshark shows the Data how I would like to broadcast and actually "capture" again.

[Wireshark Screenshot. This is how I would want to replay the data and capture it again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNjgH.png)

[This is how PlayCap broadcast is being captured by wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlit0.png)